# jQuery image loading issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent boxes on new lines from indenting on the first element.

As a test, I'm merely hard coding the boxes in html like such:

```
<ul id="box_container">
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#box_container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 23.5%;
    display: block;
    background: black;
    float: left;
}

.box + .box {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

The margin-left in the .box + .box is working as I'd like but how do I prevent it from adding the margin when the next element is forced onto another line?

I know for a fact I'll only be showing four boxes per row if that makes any difference. I was hoping to find a way to do this without having to wrap the box elements in some type of div every 4 elements but if that's the only way then I suppose I have no choice.

Here's an image of what's currently happening to give you all a better idea:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use-margin right instead of margin-left

```
.box {
        height: 300px;
        width: 22.5%;
        display: block;
        background: black;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .box + .box {
        margin-right: 2%;
    }
```

Or in real basic terms, you can use this:

```
.box:nth-child(5) {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

But this code is not optimal...

As **Bhuwan** said, use this instead of static value given above if you don't know how many inputs you might get like this:

```
.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
     margin-left: 0%;
}
```

**margin-right Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMEvmE

**margin-left codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LexmaL

Comment: The margin-left code is not optimal? Or do you mean margin-right/left is not optimal at all?

Comment: I was talking about the nth-child scenario... I'm not so proficient in css and hence I thought what if you required say 25 inputs or so... Would you add nth-child(5)(10)(15) and so on... I may be missing something on that and that's why I said it might not be optimal...

Comment: As Bhuwan answered, use ".box:nth-child(4n+1)" instead of static nth-child(5)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a margin to the left of each element, add half the margin to each side (remove the *.box + .box selector* entirely):

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 23.5%;
    display: block;
    background: black;
    float: left;
    /* ADD HALF MARGIN ON EACH SIDE OF THE BOX */
    margin: 0 1%;
}
```

You will now have vertical alignment, but with an extra 1% pushed in on either side of the container. To rectify this, pull the container back out by 1% on the left and right:

```
#box_container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /* PULL THE SIDES OUT BY 1% TO NEGATE BOX MARGINS */
    margin: 0 -1%;
}
```

This should achieve what you're trying to do, without needing to target a specific number of boxes per row.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `nth-child` css pseudo selector to remove the `margin-left`.

```
.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```css
#box_container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 23.5%;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.box+.box {
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="box_container">
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
<ul id="box_container">
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
</ul>

    #box_container {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .box {
        height: 300px;
        width: 22.5%;
        display: block;
        background: black;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .box + .box {
        margin-right: 2%;
    }
```